# What's the fastest way to vertically stack a lot of dataframes with same columns together?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

Suppose I have a list of 100 dataframes that have the same columns. Is there a way to stack them vertically that is faster than using `df.append()` 99 times? Something similar to `.join( )` for a list of strings, perhaps?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from random import randint

lst = [pd.DataFrame(np.empty([randint(1,10),3]), columns=["A","B","C"]) for i in range(100)]

DF = lst[0]

for i in range(1,100):
    DF = DF.append(lst[i])
```

Comment: Perhaps, you can try [`pd.concat(lst)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)

Comment: faster if you create a dataframe once, and instead do the concatenation within numpy : ``lst = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([np.empty([randint(1,10),3]) for i in range(100)]),columns=("A","B","C"))``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `pd.concat`:

```
lst = [pd.DataFrame(np.empty([np.random.randint(1,10),3]), columns=["A","B","C"]) for i in range(100)]

pd.concat(lst)

==>
                A              B              C
0  -3.105036e+231 -3.105036e+231  1.086944e-322
1    0.000000e+00   0.000000e+00   0.000000e+00
2    0.000000e+00   0.000000e+00   0.000000e+00
3    0.000000e+00   0.000000e+00   0.000000e+00
4    0.000000e+00  1.023640e-308 -1.494581e-154
..            ...            ...            ...
```

Comment: Here is a bit of timming info, ``append`` ==> ``57.2 ms ± 7.85 ms per loop`` & ``concat`` ==> ``8.32 ms ± 734 µs per loop``

Comment: @Sushanth Interesting. Where did you find these figures? Or did you test it yourself?

Comment: @PawinData, tested myself